# How to set variable if another variable defined in one line?

Tags: django, jinja2

I'm using this code to set variable and then check if this variable is 1:

```
{% if pillar['setup_user'] is defined %}
{% set var_setup_user = pillar['setup_user'] %}
{% else %}
{% set var_setup_user = 1 %}
{% endif %}

{% if var_setup_user == 1 %}
setup-user:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        ...

    - shell: /bin/bash
    - user: root
{% endif %}
```

Is there a way to check this in one or maybe two lines?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% set var_setup_user = pillar['setup_user']|d(1) %}
```

`d` is the alias for [default](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#default) filter.

Comment: not working, I get error. Rendering SLS 'base:base' failed: Jinja syntax error: Encountered unknown tag 'var_setup_user'.; line 20

Comment: @CroiOS Edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does a normal ternary operator work?

```
{% set var_setup_user = pillar['setup_user'] if pillar['setup_user'] is defined else 1 %}
```

Comment: `{% set var_setup_user = ... %}`.